# How to Stratify pandas DataFrame based on two columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, sample, proportions

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

[image]

```
account_num = [
    1726905620833, 1727875510892, 1727925550921, 1727925575731, 1727345507414, 
    1713565531401, 1725735509119, 1727925546516, 1727925523656, 1727875509665, 
    1727875504742, 1727345504314, 1725475539855, 1791725523833, 1727925583805, 
    1727925544791, 1727925518810, 1727925606986, 1727925618602, 1727605517337, 
    1727605517354, 1727925583101, 1727925583201, 1727925583335, 1727025517810, 
    1727935718602]
total_due = [
    1662.87, 3233.73, 3992.05, 10469.28, 799.01, 2292.98, 297.07, 5699.06, 1309.82, 
    1109.67, 4830.57, 3170.12, 45329.73, 46.71, 11981.58, 3246.31, 3214.25, 2056.82, 
    1611.73, 5386.16, 2622.02, 5011.02, 6222.10, 16340.90, 1239.23, 1198.98]
net_returned = [
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2762.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12008.27, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2762.69, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9254.66, 0.0, 0.0]
total_fees = [
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 607.78, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2161.49, 0.0, 
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 536.51, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1712.11, 0.0, 0.0]
year = [2021, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2022, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2019, 
        2018, 2018, 2022, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2022, 2019, 2021, 2022]
flipped = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
proba = [
    0.960085, 0.022535, 0.013746, 0.025833, 0.076159, 0.788912, 0.052489, 0.035279, 
    0.019701, 0.552127, 0.063949, 0.061279, 0.024398, 0.902681, 0.009441, 0.015342, 
    0.006832, 0.032988, 0.031879, 0.026412, 0.025159, 0.023195, 0.022104, 0.021285, 
    0.026480, 0.025837]

d = { 
    "account_num" : account_num,
    "total_due" : total_due,
    "net_returned" : net_returned,
    "total_fees" : total_fees,
    "year" : year,
    "flipped" : flipped,
    "proba" : proba
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to sample the DataFrame by the "year" column according to a specific ratio for each year, which I have successfully done with the following code:

```
df_fractions = pd.DataFrame({"2018": [0.5], "2019": [0.5], "2020": [1.0], "2021": [0.8], 
    "2022": [0.7]})

df.year = df.year.astype(str)
grouped = df.groupby("year")
df_training = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=df_fractions[x.name]))
df_training = df_training.reset_index(drop=True)
```

However, when I invoke sample(), I also want to ensure the samples from each year are stratified according to the number of flipped accounts in that year.  So, I want to stratify the per-year samples based on the flipped column.  With this small, toy DataFrame, after sampling per year, the ratio of flipped per year are pretty good with respect to the original proportions.  But this is not true for a really large DataFrame with close to 300K accounts.

So, that's really my question to all you Python experts: is there a better way to solve this problem than the solution I came up with?